# CSS "with latency"

Tags: html, css

I often have this kind of problem with css in my web browser. When I make some changes, or apply new or edit old style rules, it can take up to 2 hours or 5 hours before it takes an effect, even if I am not working online, I work locally, on my own server.

Last problem was z-index option, where I set:

```
#blur
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100;
    background-image: url(/images/blur-transp.png);
    background-color: rgba(150, 20, 20, 0.3);

    /* and now that z-index */
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

As this problem does not occur every time I edit css, maybe every 10th or 15th time, I think then, oh I did something wrong again. I was looking about 2 hours through my code, and finally gave up, as I just couldn't find anything illegal. Than, about 20 hours latter, I opened page in web browser again, to try to see what is going on, and, yeah, there was no error in code itself, as expected, #blur div was on the top of everything. But change applied after whole day of waiting? Why I struggle like that, is that error in web browser itself or something else? As html, php, javascripts, even my python scripts work in real time?

Comment: Did u press F5 in the browser after making the changes?

Comment: no i am pressing f+1+2+2 haha...

Comment: If all else fails, change the name of the CSS file to force the browser to update it.

Comment: What browsers did you test this in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably some caching error. What browser are you using? If Chrome, try creating a new Incognito Window to view it in. Alternatively, ctrl + shift + R or ctrl + R tends to "hard refresh" (refresh + cache refresh).

Comment: i will try that. i am using iceweasel and chromium equaly. (as my main host is kali linux). thanks for advice, will try it and let you and other people know if this helped.

Comment: yes, i just had same issue with changing z-index to -9999. refreshed page, #blur still on top. ctrl+r, and issue gone away. thanks, you deserve vote up and check mark!

Comment: you just can imagine. i am somebody who makes errors a lot, like forgeting = or ; or any other little detal accidentally

Answer (score 1):

It is because the CSS file is read from Cache once downloaded and until it is told to be refreshed or the browser does it itself.

You may either:
-Refresh your browser cache Ctrl + F5 (have you tried `F5` only before?)
-Delete the browser cache
-Add something like `?v=1.0` at the end of the CSS Url. (the browser will thead it as a different file and it will redownload it)

Answer (score 1):

Nasty cache issue, it can really upset even the most calm human being.